# stop apaches forwarding http://domain to https://domain

Tags: ssl, https, apache2, xampp

Apache is forwarding all my requests asking for http://aaa to https. How can I stop this?

httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "c:/xampp_177/htdocs/main-domain/"
  ServerName main-domain
  ServerAlias bbb
  ServerAlias aaa
</VirtualHost>
```

etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1        main-domain
127.0.0.1        bbb
127.0.0.1        aaa
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that should be causing this.  We need more configurations to look at.  Is there maybe a .htaccess file under the "wingo" directory?

Comment: Yes there is. And actually it has a mod_rewrite rule redirecting everything to https. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your .htaccess file and remove any redirects to https:// that may be there.  :-)